# Double subscript and ! Missing { inserted in LaTeX?

Tags: errors, subscripts

```
If $\textit{P}_{\textit{i}}$ is given tile \big($\textit{u,v}$\big), 
then Prob\big($H_p__i, _(u,v)$\big) = 1 while, 
Prob\big($H_p__j, _(u,v)$\big) = 0, for all j $\neq$ i.
```

Why I am getting error `! Double subscript` and `! Missing { inserted` in LaTeX?

Comment: You have two underscores in and a double subscript in `H_p__i`, tyr `H_{p_i}` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The character `$` is not for printing “special symbols” such as `\neq`, but for whole mathematical formulas.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Prob}{Prob}

\begin{document}

If $P_{i}$ is the given tile $(u,v)$, then $\Prob(H_{P_{i},(u,v)}) = 1$,
while $\Prob(H_{P_{j},(u,v)}) = 0$, for all $j\neq i$. 

\end{document}
```

I fixed `p_{i}` into `P_{i}`: I don't think there should be different symbols, should they?

There's no need to use `\big`, which adds nothing to clarity in this case. Anyway, it should go *inside* the math formula

```
$\Prob\bigl(H_{P_{i},(u,v)}\bigr) = 1$
```

[image]